# How to get all Wikipedia hyperlinks from a webpage using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, web-scraping, hyperlink

I want to get all hyperlinks from Wikipedia page that lead to another Wikipedia page in C#.
For example:

[image]

On the screenshot above you can see that I only want to get the links that lead to another Wiki article (red rects), even though there are another links on the page. I have written a function that scrapes every link on the page and returns a HashSet of them, its body is as follows:

```
private async Task<HashSet<string>> GetPages(CrawlerPage page)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# console program");
            var htmlContent = await client.GetStringAsync(page.mainLink);

            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
            var programmerLinks = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("li")
                .Where(node => !node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("tocsection")).ToList();

            HashSet<string> wikiLinks = new();

            foreach (var link in programmerLinks)
            {
                if (link.FirstChild.Attributes.Count > 0)
                    wikiLinks.Add("https://en.wikipedia.org/" + link.FirstChild.Attributes[0].Value);
            }

            return wikiLinks;
        }
```

The function works fine, but it scrapes **everything**. Have a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

You can see that the things in red rects are the links that I want to get, the rest is junk (links not needed by me).

I figured out that all of these links are under `<p>` tag in HTML, and the links are in `<a href>` but I still cannot figure out how to get these concrete links.

Can you tell me how can I get these desired links?

Thanks!

Comment: You described the logic and you have the HtmlDocument that allows you to access all nodes. What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="*">`?

Comment: Btw. it looks like all your links are inside the /wiki/ folder, so you could simply take all links and filter by url starts with?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come up with something like the code below, which should get only the items you need within the /wiki/.

I took the liberty to use `HtmlAgilityPack` since it's a well documented library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_powers";
            string result = "";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }

            var links = ParseLinks(result).Where(x => x.Contains("/wiki/") && !x.Contains("https://")).ToList();

            foreach (var link in links){
                Console.WriteLine(link.ToString());
            }
             List<string> ParseLinks(string html)
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
                var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
                return nodes == null ? new List<string>() : nodes.ToList().ConvertAll(
                       r => r.Attributes.ToList().ConvertAll(
                       i => i.Value)).SelectMany(j => j).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nodes doesn't seem to have a .toList() extension for some reason.

Comment: @Slagmoth refer to `System.Linq`.

Comment: Yeah, already had that. Still get Compiler Error CS1061.